# Event code error - only in Template Builder

Tags: web8.5, templating, event-system, template-builder

Firstly, this is an 8.5 instance, upgraded from 2013, upgraded from 2011. We have Audience Manager installed (and working well) and outbound email.

I have a set of custom events that subscribe (when the services are started) and execute (when publishing) as expected.

We are, however, unable to use Template Builder as it fails on initialization - stating errors with the *same event code.*

I've confirmed the custom DLL is the same version in

- \SDL Web\bin (as configured in tridion.contentmanager.config)
- \SDL Web\templates\bin (not 100% certain it *needs* to be there  likely clean later)
- \SDL Web\webservices\bin (not 100% certain it *needs* to be there  likely clean later)

I've tried this with a PT with no TBBs attached.
CPs/Pages Preview and Publish.

The error (below) only shows the first time I run Template Builder, following that the default TCM Event DLL then fails - consistently. If I restart Template Builder App - back to the first error.

ERROR ON FIRST RUN

```
Debugger: Initialization of the extension 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SDL Web\bin\CUSTOM.Tridion.Events.dll' failed.
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.TcmExtension.LoadExtensions()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.TcmExtension.InitializeExtensions()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Session..ctor(String userName)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Debugging.DebuggingEngine..ctor(DebugSession debugSession, String compoundTemplateUri, String compoundTemplateContent, Boolean preview, String userName)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Debugging.DebugSession..ctor(String sessionId, String compoundTemplateUri, String compoundTemplateContent, String itemUri, String packageContents, Boolean preview, String publicationTargetUri, String userName, Boolean logTridionClasses, TraceEventType logLevel)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Debugging.DebuggerRemoteRunner.StartDebugger(String sessionId, String compoundTemplateUri, String compoundTemplateContent, String itemUri, String packageContents, Boolean preview, String publicationTargetUri, String userName, Boolean logTridionClasses, String logLevelString, String previewDirectory, String previewUrl)


Component: Templating
Errorcode: 0
User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
THEN
Initialization of the extension 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SDL Web\bin\CUSTOM.Tridion.Events.dll' failed.
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.TcmExtension.LoadExtensions()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.TcmExtension.InitializeExtensions()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Session..ctor(String userName)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Debugging.DebuggingEngine..ctor(DebugSession debugSession, String compoundTemplateUri, String compoundTemplateContent, Boolean preview, String userName)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Debugging.DebugSession..ctor(String sessionId, String compoundTemplateUri, String compoundTemplateContent, String itemUri, String packageContents, Boolean preview, String publicationTargetUri, String userName, Boolean logTridionClasses, TraceEventType logLevel)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Debugging.DebuggerRemoteRunner.StartDebugger(String sessionId, String compoundTemplateUri, String compoundTemplateContent, String itemUri, String packageContents, Boolean preview, String publicationTargetUri, String userName, Boolean logTridionClasses, String logLevelString, String previewDirectory, String previewUrl)


Component: Templating
Errorcode: 0
User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

StackTrace Information Details:
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Debugging.Debugger.StartNewDebugger(String compoundTemplateUri, String compoundTemplateContent, String itemUri, String packageContents, Boolean preview, String publicationTargetUri, String userName, Boolean logTridionClasses, TraceEventType logLevel)
```

ERROR ON SUBSEQUENT RUNS

```
Initialization of the extension 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SDL Web\bin\CUSTOM.Tridion.Events.dll' failed.
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.TcmExtension.LoadExtensions()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.TcmExtension.InitializeExtensions()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Session..ctor(String userName)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Debugging.DebuggingEngine..ctor(DebugSession debugSession, String compoundTemplateUri, String compoundTemplateContent, Boolean preview, String userName)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Debugging.DebugSession..ctor(String sessionId, String compoundTemplateUri, String compoundTemplateContent, String itemUri, String packageContents, Boolean preview, String publicationTargetUri, String userName, Boolean logTridionClasses, TraceEventType logLevel)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Debugging.DebuggerRemoteRunner.StartDebugger(String sessionId, String compoundTemplateUri, String compoundTemplateContent, String itemUri, String packageContents, Boolean preview, String publicationTargetUri, String userName, Boolean logTridionClasses, String logLevelString, String previewDirectory, String previewUrl)


Component: CompoundTemplateWebService
Errorcode: 0
User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

StackTrace Information Details:
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Debugging.Debugger.StartNewDebugger(String compoundTemplateUri, String compoundTemplateContent, String itemUri, String packageContents, Boolean preview, String publicationTargetUri, String userName, Boolean logTridionClasses, TraceEventType logLevel)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Debugging.Debugger.StartNewDebuggerForItemUri(String compoundTemplateUri, String compoundTemplateContent, String itemUri, Boolean preview, String publicationTargetUri, String userName, Boolean logTridionClasses, TraceEventType logLevel)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.WebService.CompoundTemplateWebService.StartDebuggingWithItemUri(String compoundTemplateId, String compoundTemplateXml, String itemId, Boolean includeSystemLog, TraceEventType logLevel)
```

I'm seeing nothing **in the logs** (other than the error noted above from the Event Logs).

I've increased **logging on Template Builder** but nothing - this only logs once a certain point of *initialization* has been hit.

I've confirmed the **Services are running** as expected

- *Publisher* with Local User (permissions to read on assembly)
- *Service Host* with NETWORK SERVICES (permissions to read on assembly)

I checked with ProcMon and confirmed no *ACCESS DENIED* for Tcm activities.

Comment: Can you try changing or add the order (to the question)  in which your Custom event is being executed from your Tridion.ContentManager.config? I have noticed that there are a few changes in the way certain events are initialized with 8.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the application, there is also RedSharp. It seems that, although the version of **Log4Net* in the app and used by RedSharp is the same - there's some odd conflict and rather than falling over on one - the application simply stops.

Removing Log4Net from the application (and not touching the RedSharp instance) allows Template Builder to load and work. Not a long-term solution  I accept but workable for now.

I'm hoping the client digs deeper to resolve and I can update this post with more information on the root cause/fix.

Answer (score 2):

If you run/debug a Template in Template Builder, it will be executed on the CM Server in a process called `TcmTemplateDebugHost`. This process hosts the entire CM Kernel, including all configured extensions.

You can attach a (remote) debugger to this process to debug your .NET Template code, but also your custom extensions.

So: I would recommend to attach a debugger to`TcmTemplateDebugHost` and set it to break on all exceptions. Then try to run/debug a template and see if the debugger breaks in your custom extension.